# NodeJS Waterfall respond with different error than waterfall callback

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, async.js, waterfall

I am wondering what the proper way is to make a server response in a NodeJS Express app when an internal server error occurs. Here is some simplified code for registering users. The main issue being, if an internal server error happens, I want to log the error, but also respond to the client with a different message. What I have below is what my current solution is, but I feel like I'm not doing it properly (or not following the conventional way). I currently have an async waterfall setup which is called from the route.

```
//Controller.js
function verifyInputs(user, resCallback, callback) {
    //verify user inputs (ie. passwords match)
    if (valid) {
        callback(null)
    } else {
        resCallback('whatever was wrong with inputs', 409)
        callback('ok')
    }
}

function checkIfUserExists(user, resCallback, callback) {
    db.getPool().getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            resCallback('custom response error message', 500)
            callback(err)
            return
        }
        var sql = 'SELECT...'
        connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
            connection.release()
            if (err) {
                resCallback('another custom response error', 500)
                callback(err)
                return
            }
            if (results.length > 0) {
                resCallback('user already exists')
                callback('ok')
            }
        })
    )
}

module.exports.registerNewUser(user, callback) {
    async.waterfall([
        async.apply(user, callback, verifyInputs),
        async.apply(user, callback, checkIfUserExists)
    ],
    function(err, reults) {
        if (err === 'ok') return
        //log error or whatever here    
    })
}
```

This register function is called from the routes function:

```
//Router.js
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    var newUser = //get user data from req
    controller.registerNewUser(newUser, (msg, statusCode) => {
        res.statusCode(statusCode)
        res.send(msg)
    })
})
```

The code above shows how I log the error while responding to the client with a different message. Is this the right or an OK way to do this?

Or maybe I shouldn't use a waterfall at all for this, and do something like this which would give me access to the res object at all stages without multiple callbacks:

```
router.post('/register', verifyInputs(), checkIfUserExists(), (req, res, next) => {
    var newUser = //get user data from req
    controller.registerNewUser(newUser, (msg, statusCode) => {
        res.statusCode(statusCode)
        res.send(msg)
    })
})
```

I'm relatively new to server back end programming, and I am new to NodeJS and Express. I just want to make sure what I am doing the proper.